# EKEvents/EKReminders set but are not displaying on calendar

Tags: ios6, reminders, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I am setting events to calendar. The code works throughly but wen I check if the event r set on my device's calendar. It doesnt show anything. I am doing this in ios6, when I do it for ios5, it works fine.

Comment: facing the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734436/saveevent-returning-no-calendar-has-been-set

Comment: Please update if u find solution.. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, you can try the same.
I had to navigate from one page to another, so posting the link to the two pages.

First -> https://discussions.apple.com/message/16497282#16497282

Then, from there to -> https://discussions.apple.com/message/16479587#16479587

I had to go into Settings>iCloud> and turn on Calendars. After that, I tried to attempt and run my code, and it was working well and fine again.

Do attempt this, if you facing a similar problem.

I was working on iPad 2, and with iOS 6.1.3 installed on the device.